# cfquery taking much longer

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

A simple query like

```
SELECT TOP 1 ColName FROM <TABLE> WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SomeFieldName='xxxxx'
```

is taking lot of time in CF. Same query when run in management studio, runs without any issues. It has the index on SomeFieldName. I have FusionReactor installed. It shows it taking 25-35 seconds. The query plan in dev doesn't suggest anything.
What is going wrong here? Could indexes an issue? (I do not have access to them in prod).
ColdFusion 2018.
Edit: Same queries run alright on CF2016

Comment: More probable that coldfusion does something on its own

Comment: Show the code you're actually using in ColdFusion.

Comment: Side notes: do you *need* the `NOLOCK`? Do you understand what it does? Why are you using a `TOP` with no `ORDER BY`? Your statement is missing columns in the `SELECT`, so it'll error in SSMS.

Comment: @Larnu, that is the exact query, I have in cfquery bar the masked table, col names. I fully understand about NOLOCK and why we have it. My issue is not with NOLOCK. This query shows up taking 25-35 sec in monitor.

Comment: @Sergey, that is what I am trying to understand if someone faced same issue and corrective measures taken.

Comment: Without table structures, indexes or an execution plan this is impossible to answer...or maybe this is nothing like your actual query and you are using parameters and getting bad parameter sniffing.

Comment: Does this happen with all queries or just this one?

Comment: How old is the driver you're using?
And what settings are you using in the setup of the coldfusion datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally found the answer for slow running queries though still do not know why does that happen.

The `SomeFieldName` column is data type `varchar`. CF2018, somehow is sending varchar parameters as `nvarchar` to SQL Server. So, indexes does not work correctly. We found that in SQL monitor.

We checked the *String Format* check box in CF Admin, that checkbox is not enabled, so not sure why it would send varchar as nvarchar.
We reset the CF admin setting, checked the box, saved, unchecked again, saved and reset the instance and it started working correctly.

Comment: So are you saying the data type of the `SomeFieldName` column  is actually `varchar`, but was being submitted as `Nvarchar`?

Comment: @SOS, Correct. SQL monitor showed that parameter coming as nvarchar. After the reset, it started coming as varchar and query started running in few ms instead of 25+ secs

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Added to the answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem

Comment: Where is this setting for the "string format"?